# Crypto++ generating AES key to a file

Tags: c++, c++17, crypto++

I generate key to a file using the following function

```
std::filesystem::path create_key(std::filesystem::path folder_path)
{

    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool prng;
    CryptoPP::byte key[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
    prng.GenerateBlock(key, sizeof(key));

    std::cout << "Size of key : " << sizeof(key) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Key before hex encode : " << (CryptoPP::byte*)&key << std::endl;

    std::filesystem::path key_path = folder_path.concat("\key.aes");
    
    // Key hex encoded to file
    CryptoPP::StringSource key_s((CryptoPP::byte*)&key, sizeof(key), true,
        new CryptoPP::HexEncoder(
            new CryptoPP::FileSink(key_path.c_str())));


    std::cout << key_path << "\n" << std::endl;
    return key_path;

}
```

I use same function with few modifications for IV

I get the following results:

```
Size of key : 16
Key before hex encode : %
"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\New folder\\key.aes"

Size of IV : 16
IV before hex encode : á▀┼┘ÅP⌐ûG→.JW╓‼Ñg79▓─G
"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\New folder\\iv.aes"
```

Obviously after encoding the results look more readable ,
Does the key should use this characters ?
How can I read the the key and iv using crypto++

I have tried reversing the function :

```
CryptoPP::FileSource key(key_path.c_str(), sizeof(key), true,
        new CryptoPP::HexDecoder(
            new CryptoPP::StringSink((CryptoPP::byte*)&key),key_path.c_str()));
```

And use it by loading keys and IV but it didn't worked

I checked the `key.aes` file and found out it's created in `ANSI` encoding which make difference in few characters is there a way to make it `utf-8`

Console prints : `╢╘r#|ÿ┴♀[ÉB!±L↨SXêu:▄`

Key.aes file : `¶Ôr#|˜Á[B!ñLS`

converting key.aes file to utf-8 results : `¶Ôr#|˜Á[B!ñLS`

Comment: Pop quiz: how does `<<` to `std::cout` know how many characters to print from a `const char*`? If you know the answer to this you should know what's happening here.

Comment: Hint: is `key` a `std::string` or nul-terminated C-string?

Comment: `std::string` is null terminated , in my case I use `crypto::byte` array , I did a test and exported the key to a file before encoding and after the key remains the same which means everything works , but the question remains if I use `CryptoPP::StringSink(test)));`  How can I use the key from file ?

Comment: Using ` CryptoPP::ArraySink((byte*)&key_test, sizeof(key_test))));`  produces same result worth to mention I have updated the key_test to be     `CryptoPP::byte key_test[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
    CryptoPP::byte key[CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];`

Comment: I used the key as is and it worked but I still don't understand why the output got extra 6 bytes

Comment: I checked the key.aes file and found out it's created in ANSI encoding which make difference in few characters is there a way to make it utf-8

Console prints : `╢╘r#|ÿ┴♀[ÉB!±L↨SXêu:▄`
Key.aes file : `¶Ôr#|˜Á[B!ñLS`
converting key.aes file to utf-8 results : `¶Ôr#|˜Á[B!ñLS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is valid and works ,
No changes need to be added in my scenario.